# What (emulated?) architecture does Windows Azure run on?

Tags: architecture, azure, amazon-ec2

[EC2 tells you](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) the architecture of their giant instance types (e.g. 2 x Intel Xeon X5570, quad-core “Nehalem” architecture), but refuses to be specific about their small instance types. What about Azure?

Comment: Not sure I follow your question but http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0019p shows what the compute instance sizes are.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @klabranche I edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: AFAIK, Microsoft hasn't made that info public, but you might try installing CPU-Z on a Windows Azure instance (using Remote Desktop), and see what it reports.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question, do you mean hypervisor layer? EC2 (AWS) runs on a 'modified' copy Xen hypervisor, Azure 'extremely modified Hyper V with Fabric Controller Layer'

This billing page might give you a better look at the Azure instances: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/